# Nginx, too many redirects, err_too_many_redirects

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have been learning and testing various installations of NGINX for proxy_pass (both custom compilation and standard install) using 2 servers. The problem(s) that I am having relate to "err_too_many_redirects"; Specifically, there are many references to clearing cache (I use Chrome) but that does not resolve the problem. I have also looked at the regular expressions hoping to find any misconfiguraitons, but so far nothing (from RTFM) has shown me anything that suggests a misconfiguration.

Primary server has a single domain, standard install, only 1 additional "server directive" noted below. The secondary server also has a standard install with a completely different domain name which resolves fine locally, just not from external requests (i.e. "hosts" file is configured).

```
server {

    server_name my2ndweb.com *.my2ndweb.com;

    location ~* {
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    }

    ...

}
```

I have also modified the location directive with "/" instead of "~*", as well as the FQDN at the "proxy_pass" statement (I read somewhere the hosts file would resolve it rather than re-directing to a local address...did nothing for it though);

Anyway, this all works if I use a single server and just place the different domains within different folder structures, but that defeats the purpose of having a failover option if one server breaks...-no I did not configure failover, just thinking about it.

NOTE: There is no other error in the logs whatsoever regarding redirects!

k/r
axetone

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER:

I made the mistake of not removing the wildcard "*" from the nginx.conf file path statement that points to the directory (or in this case with the wildcard DIRECTORIES) used for the site configurations...~thus the error(s) I was given at reload time pointing to a line item error was actually in one of the other conf files and NOT my "default" conf file.

Silly silly mistake!

Solution: Replace the wildcard "*" from the end of the "include.." path statement in nginx.conf and instead use the actual folder/file name ONLY.

Ex:
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

REPLACE WITH:
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default;   # or whatever your filename is.